# I want to make search box to get data from mysql by android studio

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, crud

Can some one help me.I can insert data to mysql by android studio.But i'm not sure how to get data from mysql to android studio. please help me and show example or answer by my code for more understand.(Sorry for my bad English.)
(It not error but i want to guild line. :( )

```
Conn.php  
<?php  
 $db_name = "employee101";  
 $mysql_username = "root";  
 $mysql_password = "";  
 $server_name = "localhost";  
 $conn = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_username,$mysql_password,$db_name);  
?>
> 
>
```

login.php

```
require "conn.php";
$name = $_POST["name"];
$surname = $_POST["surname"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$mysql_qry = "insert into employee_data(name, surname, age, username, password) value ('$name','$surname','$age','$username','$password')";
if($conn->query($mysql_qry) === TRUE){
echo "Insert Success";
}
else
{
    echo"Insert not success".$mysql_qry."<br>". $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
```

Backgroundwoker.java

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

/**
 * Created by puen on 4/6/2016.
 */
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    BackgroundWorker (Context ctx){
        context = ctx;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String login_url = "http://192.168.10.125/login.php";
        String register_url = "http://192.168.10.125/register.php";
        if(type.equals("login")){
            try {
                String user_name = params[1];
                String password = params[2];
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }else if (type.equals("register")){
            try {
                String name = params[1];
                String surname = params[2];
                String age = params[3];
                String username = params[4];
                String password = params[5];
                URL url = new URL(register_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                +URLEncoder.encode("surname","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(surname,"UTF-8")+"&"
                +URLEncoder.encode("age","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(age,"UTF-8")+"&"
                +URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

register.java

```
package com.example.puen.mysqldemo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText name, surname, age, username, password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_name);
        surname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_surname);
        age = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_age);
        username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_username);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_password);



    }
    public void OnReg(View view){
        String str_name = name.getText().toString();
        String str_surname = surname.getText().toString();
        String str_age = age.getText().toString();
        String str_username = username.getText().toString();
        String str_password = password.getText().toString();

        String type = "register";
        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
        backgroundWorker.execute(type, str_name, str_surname, str_age, str_username, str_password);
        }

        }
```

Comment: What's the error? Where are you trying to fetch the data?

Comment: It not error.But i need a guild line for make it. Cuz i learnning from website  and i can't not make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retrieve details of user from mysql, use JSON to encode the information. The code would look somewhat like this:

```
<?php
     $username = $_POST['username'];

        require_once('Connect.php');

     $sql = "select * from account_info where username='$username';";

     $res = mysql_query($sql);
     $num=mysql_num_rows($res);
     if($num>0)
     {
        $result= array();
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
            array_push($result, array('name'=>$row[1],'phone'=>$row[2]));

            echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

     }
     else
     {
        echo "No accounts ";
     }
     mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Then retrieve this information in JSONArray in Android  using JSONObject.

For example:

let JSONString be the result you get after sending your query to php script through Async Task.

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSONString);
            array = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);

Comment: And i will add more code in Backgroundwoker.java and register.java
or make you JSON.php only?
So sorry for my stupid Questions. And thank you.

Comment: after you fetch the array, use 
JSONObject obj=array.getJSONObject(index);
String username=obj.getString("name"); 
// to fetch the information

Comment: sorry and can you tell me about code to show on listview.

Comment: For creating listView, use Fragment along with your Activity.
You have to create an instance of ArrayAdapter and pass your arrayList to its constructor. Then set the listView with this adapter which would display the contents. 
You can get more information about ListView from this link:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_view.htm